# Does Facebook Android SDK session give short or long term Token?

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

Does `session.getAccessToken()` give a short or long term access token?

And more importantly if short term is it a good idea to call

```
GET /oauth/access_token?
   client_id={app-id}
   &client_secret={app-secret}
   &grant_type=client_credentials
```

from the android app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found that `session.getExpirationDate()` returns a 2 months from now Date. That at least works with my profile so I believe that will do with the other users. So long-term token it is.